# Translate images with google translate using python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, image-translation

I want to use google translate web (https://translate.google.com/) to translate images and save translated image using python, here is my code :

```py
import json
import requests
import base64
import os


def guess_type(image_path):
    # Get the file extension from the image path
    ext = os.path.splitext(image_path)[1].lower()

    # Map the extensions to the mimetypes
    mimetypes = {
        ".jpg": "image/jpeg",
        ".jpeg": "image/jpeg",
        ".png": "image/png"
    }

    # Return the mimetype if it exists, otherwise return None
    return mimetypes.get(ext, None)
def load_image_as_base64(image_path):
    with open(image_path, 'rb') as f:
        image_bytes = f.read()

    # Convert image bytes to base64 string
    base64_string = base64.b64encode(image_bytes).decode('utf-8')
    mimetype = guess_type(image_path)

    # Return image data in the specified format
    return [base64_string, mimetype]

_imageObj = load_image_as_base64('124+958.png')


_RPCIDS = "WqWDPb"
params = {
    'rpcids': _RPCIDS,
    'bl': 'boq_translate-webserver_20240115.08_p0',
    'soc-app': 1,
    'soc-platform': 1,
    'soc-device': 1,
    'rt': 'c'
    }

data = {'f.req': json.dumps([[
    [_RPCIDS,
    json.dumps([_imageObj,"auto","fr"], separators=(',', ':')),
     None,
     "generic"]
    ]], separators=(',', ':')),
 }



TRANSLATEURL = 'https://translate.google.com/_/TranslateWebserverUi/data/batchexecute'


response = requests.request("POST", TRANSLATEURL,
                            data=data,
                            params=params,
                            )
```

then i use bellow code to get translated image :

```py
import base64

def convert_base64_to_image(base64_string, image_path):
    # Convert base64 string to image bytes
    image_bytes = base64.b64decode(base64_string)

    # Write the image bytes to a file
    with open(image_path, 'wb') as image_file:
        image_file.write(image_bytes)

b = response.text.split('\n')
li_filter = []
flag = False
for _b in b:
  if _b.isnumeric():
    flag = not flag
    _b = '==='
  if flag:
    li_filter.append(_b)

li_data = json.loads(li_filter[1])

resp_img_data =json.loads(li_data[0][2])
res_img_data=resp_img_data[0]
f_mimetypes = {
       "image/jpg": ".jpg" ,
        "image/jpeg" :".jpeg",
       "image/png" : ".png"
}
convert_base64_to_image(res_img_data[0], 'out'+f_mimetypes[res_img_data[1]])
```

but result image is my input image , nothing changed and not translated.
I also checked json response,but it doesn't contain original and translated text in image.
what is the problem?